# Cannot Enable php 7 thread safety on Mac

Tags: php, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I have just upgraded my php 5.5 to php 7 and I need to install pthreads, before installing pthreads I need "Thread Safety" to be enabled but I cannot find the line to enable "thread safety" in `php.ini` file on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enable thread safety at runtime, it is a build time configuration option only.